# What causes a query to exclude first record

Tags: php, html, mysql

PHP and MySQL:What causes a query to exclude the first record in a table:
for example i have a script like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_name = 'BMW'";
$results = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Vehicle Name:<th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $name = $row['car_name'];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$name<td>";
      echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

All rows are returned except the first one.Please help a brother out folks.

Comment: Maybe in first row `car_name` is not `BMW`? maybe it's `bmw` or `Bmw`?

Comment: It may possible your first entry has space in start...

Comment: what do you get when you run your query in MySQL console? All rows?

Comment: How did you know that your query `exclude the first row` since your query doesn't `ordered by`?

Comment: @iroegbu - Good question,All rows do appear when i use MySQL console, that's the funny part.could it be my php script mybe - i don't:what could be the possible causes of this?

Comment: .... Dude... you realise you're selecting WHERE car_name=BMW AND only showing the car_name in your PHP... that means you're going to have a whole list of
`BMW
BMW
BMW` (how do you know it is the first one...)

Comment: Your <td> has no closing tag (just another opening tag). Is it possible that you ARE getting the first row but the browser is hiding it (try doing a _view source_ ).

Comment: @Kickstart that is a good catch that I didn't look for... I THINK (key word) tds will close themselves, but the fact that he has 2 opening it would lead me to think it was more likely he would lose the last one. Not 100% on this, but it is worth closing it because it is the proper way.

Comment: Guys this is just an example of what i did, i'll post the whole script now.

Comment: Oh oops, obviously can''t post the whole script,too long.But i'll try some of your suggestions.Thanks guys

Comment: @Stan I think I got it. I think you need to change the mysql function check my edited answer.

Comment: @CayceK - Finally solved the problem, i just change to a do while loop and it worked,don't really know what the problem is with a while tho.but thanks a lot mate.

Comment: DO..WHILE would make sense to fix it if you had a line of code saying _$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);_ before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last 
column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the same name,
you must use the numeric index of the column or make an alias for the 
column. For aliased columns, you cannot access the contents with the 
original column name
```

You are using mysql_fetch_array and this is what it says in the documentation. I never use mysql* functions so I wouldn't have jumped to this type of conclusion quickly. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc($results)` and I'm 99% sure it will resolve your issue. The why this would be different is in the paragraph above from the documentation. I assume your first row is identical to at least 1 of the below rows. Which means it is very likely you're missing more than just the first one. May or may not be the case.

**END EDIT**

Add 4 things to your code.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>"; // THIS
echo "<th>Vehicle Name:</th>"; // Add closing tags........
echo "</tr>";
echo mysql_num_rows($results); // THIS (compare this to your MYSQL output row count)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){ **THIS... you have $results set with query, but $result here*** make sure both are $results OR $result
      $id = $row['YOUR_AI_ID']; // THIS
      $name = $row['car_name'];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$id</td>"; // THIS
      echo "<td>$name</td>"; // Add closing tags.......
      echo "</tr>";
}
```

Go go do now. Come back with results.

Comment: Ok now we getting somewhere,after echoing num_rows it returns the number of rows that i want...but still excludes the first row.so what could be the problem now?

Comment: a whole slew of things could do it. But we are more worried about which ID is missing and why. So use this layout type and change the `YOUR_AI_ID` to the id of the auto incremented id that you use for the rows in your mysql... If you do not use an AI number please use something that is different in each row.

Comment: Did that, still no results

Comment: ok... did you close your `<td>` and `<th>` tags... if you haven't just close them with `</td>` and `</th>` respectively

Comment: I'm on it-thaks:i'm trying a whole lot of things right now

Comment: Ok... also last thing I noticed is that `$results = mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_array($result)` are not the same. make sure they are the same. Though you should not get any results in this case if they are different.

Comment: Closed tags everything Still there's  nothing.and about result variable that's not even close to being an issue.this is wierd really..why does it see the total number of rows when returning the results it excludes the first row.im not sleeping till i get this right...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:
Let's take a peak at your table `cars`.
What does

```
$qs = array(
    array('total #rows', 'SELECT Count(*) FROM cars'),
    array('#BMW', "SELECT Count(*) FROM cars WHERE car_name='BMW'"),
    array('#LIKE BMW', "SELECT Count(*) FROM cars WHERE car_name LIKE '%BMW%'"),
    array('#car_names', "SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT distinct car_name as foo FROM cars) as bar")
);

foreach( $qs as $query ) {
    echo $query[0], "<br />\r\n";
    $result = mysql_query($query[1]) or die(mysql_error());
    while ( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) ) {
        echo '  ', $row[0], "\r\n";
    }
}
```

print if placed in your script instead of your posted code?
The output should be something like

```
total #rows<br />
  6
#BMW<br />
  2
#LIKE BMW<br />
  3
#car_names<br />
  4
```

BTW: the mysql_* extension is deprecated,
see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: So mysqli_* is the solution you record?

Comment: Finally solved the problem, i just change to a do while loop and it worked,don't really know what the problem is with a while tho.but thanks a lot mate.